# Python - ftplib.FTP_TLS Port

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone help me confirm the default port when using ftplib.FTP_TLS? We have opened port 990 and 21 but my script fails to connect.

```
import ftplib

session = ftplib.FTP_TLS('xxx.ftp.com','user','password')
file = open('Bkup.tar.gz','rb')
session.storbinary('STOR Bkup.tar.gz', file)
file.close()
session.quit()
```

Thank You!

Comment: The default port is 21 for ftplib: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html

Comment: I read that as well, but am not sure why our firewall is still blocking the script.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
ftplib.FTP_TLS.port = 21
```

Comment: You should always try to explain *how* your solution works. Code-only answers are likely to be deleted, because they don't help people to understand the solution.

Comment: Afte rmany many problems with explicit FTP connections, this was the answer that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

According to it's own documentation, as well as the spec, FTPS (or FTP over TLS) connects to port 21.

You appear to be missing a login clause to authenticate the session.

Try calling `session.login()` followed by `session.prot_p()` before attempting to store the binary.

This documentation can be found by using the `help` function or in the [online documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP_TLS).

I hope that helps.

Comment: If we allow all traffic from this server, the script works and copies the file successfully to the backup site.

Comment: Does prot_p() use port 21 as well? Using TCPDUMP I see the destination port of 21, but then it switches to 2392.

Comment: I believe it should. There is nothing that I can find in the specification of FTPS, FTP, or TLS that directly references port 2932.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't modify the port directly. If you get a closer look at `FTP_TLS` super `__init__` you can clearly see that if it's called with a host param `connect` gets automatically called with just the host as param so the port defaults to `FTP_PORT` which is 21.

A better approach would be to call `FTP_TLS` without any params and then manually call the `connect` method where you can specify host as well as port.

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
client = FTP_TLS()
client.connect(host="ftp.example.com", port=12121)
```

Answer (score -1):

Oddly, the [FTP_TLS](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP_TLS) object has no direct port parameter on the constructor like the [FTP](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftp-objects) object does.

you can set the port prior to calling the constructor and that works.

```
ftplib.FTP_TLS.port=1234
ftplib.FTP_TLS( 'ftphost.domain.tld', 'user', 'password' )
```